# Create a sum of form values using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am aiming to create a form to generate a quick quote. The ambition is that theu ser is able to select computer parts with a value assigned to each  > .

For instance,

```
<form id="formsum">
  <select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="5">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form id="formsum2">
  <select>
  <option value="2">1</option>
  <option value="10">2</option>
  <option value="4">3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

So if the user selects option 2 on formsum and then 2 on formsum2 Id like the function to read "15".

Comment: so where you have written your `js` code?

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: I started a codepen but it wasnt working so i deleted it. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great :) im fairly new to this so im not sure what search terms to use or jquery terms to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Selected value of select and add it.

Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to parse selected value into int.

```js
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
   var sum  = parseInt($('#formsum select').val()) + parseInt($('#formsum2 select').val());
   console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formsum">
  <select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="5">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form id="formsum2">
  <select>
  <option value="2">1</option>
  <option value="10">2</option>
  <option value="4">3</option>
  </select>
</form>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="show"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, looks like i need to read up on parseint!

Comment: @jbibb917 : hope it solved your problem. then accept it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
$("[id^=formsum] select").change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $("[id^=formsum] select").each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(sum)
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("[id^=formsum] select").change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $("[id^=formsum] select").each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(sum)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formsum">
  <select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="5">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form id="formsum2">
  <select>
  <option value="2">1</option>
  <option value="10">2</option>
  <option value="4">3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: @pedram what do you mean, if i select 2 in both it returns 15

Comment: @Jackowski The OP says ` function to read "15"` when option 2 in both are select, aka mine does that. So why do you think the code is wrong, i have used the same code as the OP

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i know sorry, i missunderstood the question. I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out on both dropdown change event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formsum,#formsum2").change(function() {
    var sum  = parseInt($('#formsum select').val()) + parseInt($('#formsum2 select').val());
    alert(sum);
    });
});
```